# Habilitar aplicaciones del almacen SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

Hola soy bastante nuevo con sharepoint y estoy intentando instalar aplicaciones desde el Almacén de SharePoint pero no me deja y me dice lo siguiente:

> Lo sentimos, las aplicaciones están desactivadas. Si sabe quién ejecuta el servidor, pídale que habilite las aplicaciones.

He intentado seguir [este](http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2012/07/29/setting-up-your-app-domain-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx) tutorial para habilitar las aplicaciones pero al llegar a este paso:
[image: Configure your app url]

No me permite configurar nada. No se realmente lo que estoy haciendo mal o porque no puede seguir a partir de este paso.

Pdta: Se que existe un [sitio](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) expecifico para dudas de SharePoint pero necesito una respuesta en español ya que sufiente complejo me parece entender SharePoint en español como para intentar comprenderlo en Ingles.

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Para poder subir y mantener aplicaciones en sharepoint, lo primero que debes hacer es crear el sitio que las aloja. Más específicamente, un catálogo de aplicaciones. Una vez que crees este sitio, tendrás opciones sobre éstas como la de "distribución de aplicaciones", que te permitirá crear un nueva aplicación, actualizarla, etc. Luego verás como opción en "Agregar aplicación" desde el sitio que deseas instalarla. Saludos.

Comment: si tu sitio de sharepoint esta en ingles, te recomendaria utilizar el sitio en ingles, yo solo he utilizado versiones de sharepoint en ingles y no entiendo nada de lo que tratas de decir.